# C#/Windows MediaPlayer: Handle clicks on buttons

Tags: c#, media-player

Simple question: I have an AxWindowsMediaPlayer component and I want to modify the OnPlayButtonClick event, which does not seem to exist. Any idea of a work around?

It should be something in terms of this:

```
private void OnPlayButtonClick() {
  MessageBox.Show('Hello World');
  if (wmPlayer.playState.ToString().Equals("wmppsPlaying"))
    wmPlayer.Ctlcontrols.pause();
  else
    wmPlayer.Ctlcontrols.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could select that control and look at the properties windows and click the lightening bolt you will see all the events you can subscribe to for that control.  I dont think there is an playbuttonclick event you can subscribe to, I think you would need to subscribe to playstatechanged and at that point check the play state and perform operations based off what it is.  You could do something like this:

```
private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.newState.ToString());
    }
```

Or you could create custom buttoms to perform the play, pause, stop functions and perform what ever actions needed in the event handlers of those buttons.